# How to refactor repeating code in Pandoc lua filter

Tags: lua, pandoc

I am in the process of writing a Lua filter for Pandoc specifically targeting Pandoc generated LaTeX documents.

Here is a small code snippet from my filter:

```
LATEX_CODES_FOR_TAGS = {
  Span = {
    sans = '\\sffamily ',
    serif = '\\rmfamily ',
  },
  Div = {
    -- Font Styles
    sans = '\\begin{sffamily}',
    serif = '\\begin{rmfamily}',
  }
}

function Span(span)
  for tag, code_for_class in pairs(LATEX_CODES_FOR_TAGS) do
    for class, code in pairs(code_for_class) do
      if tag == "Span" then
        if span.classes:includes(class) then
          table.insert(span.content, 1, pandoc.RawInline('latex', code))
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return span
end

function Div(div)
  for tag, code_for_class in pairs(LATEX_CODES_FOR_TAGS) do
    for class, code in pairs(code_for_class) do
      if tag == "Div" then
        if div.classes:includes(class) then
          local code_end = code:gsub('begin', 'end')
          table.insert(div.content, 1, pandoc.RawBlock('latex', code))
          table.insert(div.content, pandoc.RawBlock('latex', code_end))
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return div
end
```

As you can see the code for the `Div()` and `Span()` functions are almost exactly the same, and therefore want to refactor the code.

I have hitherto been unable to come up with a solution that makes the filter without the repeating code.

I am still very new to Lua and wrapping my head around the concepts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the body of the loop as a separate function:

```
local function create_handler(tag_str, handler_func)
   return
      function (obj)
         for tag, code_for_class in pairs(LATEX_CODES_FOR_TAGS) do
            for class, code in pairs(code_for_class) do
               if tag == tag_str then
                  if obj.classes:includes(class) then
                     handler_func(obj, code)
                  end
               end
            end
         end
         return obj
      end
end

Span = create_handler("Span",
   function(span, code)
      table.insert(span.content, 1, pandoc.RawInline('latex', code))
   end)

Div = create_handler("Div",
   function(div, code)
      local code_end = code:gsub('begin', 'end')
      table.insert(div.content, 1, pandoc.RawBlock('latex', code))
      table.insert(div.content, pandoc.RawBlock('latex', code_end))
   end)
```

Comment: Thanks @egor-skriptunoff I had not thought of returning a function within a function. I guess this is a key feature of Lua that I need to master.